# node-ssdp API for Sonos is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sonos

I'm trying to figure out how to interact with the Sonos One using JavaScript; Sonos has developer guides and downloads for JavaScript but none of them work, because the node-ssdp project has been archived and is no longer available. Does anyone have a reference or a contact at Sonos through which we can access the devices directly? The cloud API *works* but is a lot heavier than talking to the devices directly over a LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this ended up being a dumb question. Sonos apparently forked node-ssdp and hosted their own for a while, and the standard npm node-ssdp library works fine for this purpose.

Remove the node-ssdp dependency from the package.json, then:

`npm i node-ssdp`

Not everything works, because the Sonos samples in JS were written for very old versions of Node and have not been updated, but the base packages are fine.